# I want to know more about this ink painting

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

Hi recently I got a really nice ink painting and I want to know more about it and not sure if the language is Chinese or Japanese. I am a big fan of art so I am always open to learn more.

If anyone has the time to tell me who the artist is and what the art is called I'd love to know.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a Chinese traditional painting of the style called [花鳥畫](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird-and-flower_painting) (Huaniaohua - Bird-and-flower painting).

- 粉妝樓曉 (given name/topic of the painting), 丁陽 (author).

Comment: What is that translated into English though?

Comment: It describes/implies a pretty woman (粉妝 - the focusing flower) in the early morning (曉) at the upper story of a building (樓).